# Has the positivity part in Lusztig's conjecture been solved?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, modular-representation-theory

In Lusztig's paper "BASE IN EQUIVARIANT K- THEORY Ⅱ", He stated a conjecture about the positivity of coefficients in his famous conjecture.
Precisely, (In 9.20) He conjectured that

$\tilde{\pi}_{A,B}\in\mathbb{N}[v^{-1}]$ for all $A<B$,

$\pi_{B,A}\in\mathbb{N}[-v^{-1}]$ for all $B<A$,

where the $\pi_{B,A}$ is the $[Z_B:L_A]$ in has conjecture (17.3) in standard Levi form.

What is current status about this conjecture? I known there is a counterexample about this conjecture by Geordie Williamson, but the positivity issue seems still open.